# E3276 on ubuntu

Tags: networking, 17.10, usb-modem, modem, usb-modeswitch

**EDIT: 
solved the issue. I have inserted sim card wrong side - checked it on widonws that gave me hint**

I have E3276 modem and it is shining blue

```
kamil@kamil-K53SV:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0234 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I used to connect to internet after these commands:

```
kamil@kamil-K53SV:~$ sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000101000100000000000000'
Look for default devices ...
 No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye!

kamil@kamil-K53SV:~$ sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1506 -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000101000100000000000000'
Look for default devices ...
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 003 on bus 002
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
 with class 255
Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0; interface class is 255, expected 8. Abort
```

Now it does not work

Also i tried:
https://askubuntu.com/a/700387/755206
and

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x1506
```

How can i make it work again?

Comment: Why did you need to run this command just to connect, aught it not to be a simple plug & play?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i solved the issue. I have inserted sim card wrong side - checked it on widonws that gave me hint

Comment: Great that it was solved!